# change image after x seconds with loop mouseenter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image in HTML, and I wish when the mouse enter in image, this image change quickly, with an infinite loop. I have a lot of image to display (logo_white, logo_red, logo_blue, logo_green, ...)

HTML

```
<img src="img/logo_white.png" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
```

JS

```
$('#logo').mouseenter(function() {
        var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'img/logo_white.png')
            ? 'img/logo_red.png'
            : 'img/logo_white.png';
            $(this).attr('src', src);
    });
```

This JS code "work". But I think it could be better.
Thanks you in advance for your response.

Comment: Is there a question here, or something that is not working?  Very confusing.

Comment: He wants better JS code apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a 100% sure what you mean, but maybe an example like this is what you are looking for or can get you started.

This example:

- Create an array with the links to your images
- Preload these images
- For the '`mouseenter`' event start an interval and switch the logo to the next one in the array (Or continue where it left off)
- For the '`mouseleave`' event, stop the interval.
- Initializes the first image when the page is fully loaded including graphics. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

You can change the variable `intervalInMilliseconds` to speed it up or slow it down.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var interval;
        var currentImageNumber = 0;
        var intervalInMilliseconds = 1000;
        var images = [
            "img/logo_green.png",
            "img/logo_blue.png",
            "img/logo_red.png",
            "img/logo_white.png"
        ];

        function preload(arrayOfImages) {
            $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
                (new Image()).src = this;
            });
        }

        function switchLogo(imageNumber) {
            $('#logo').attr('src', images[imageNumber]);
            currentImageNumber = currentImageNumber === images.length -1 ? 0 : ++currentImageNumber;
        }

        preload(images);

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var logo = $('#logo');

            logo.mouseenter(function() {
                interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                    switchLogo(currentImageNumber)
                }, intervalInMilliseconds);
            });

            logo.mouseleave(function() {
                clearInterval(interval);
            });
        });

        // When all the images are loaded
        $(window).load(function() {
            // Initialize this to the first image
            switchLogo(currentImageNumber);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="" alt="Logo" id="logo" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Thank You